# CodeIgniter URI using Wildcards page not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

Explaining my situation first, I want to create a Dynamic Page using CI. I found in the URI routing that I can use WildCards, which I used it to pass an ID to a function in the controller to retrieve from the Database.

Through using my routing file [which in the routing I change which Controller and Function to Call].

1) my URL in the Default_Routing is : 
**localhost/CI/**

2) when I navigate to the other links, I would get:
**localhost/CI/about**

3) when I use the wildcard I get this URL:
**localhost/CI/member/11**

- whereas I use segment(3) to get '11'

4) But while I'm in that page I try to navigate to the 'about' link again, I get:
**localhost/CI/member/about**

- Which somehow 'member' stays in the URL and adds 'about' after it instead of just **localhost/CI/about**

From the Manual I think _remap can fix that problem (which I'm not sure) and I don't how to fix this problem, or I'm using a wrong approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use base_url() or site_url() functions for your links, then the links will be structured with localhost/CI/ in front.

Comment: **base_url()** worked for me, but is there another way instead of just adding base_url next to every link in the href in the navagation bar?

Comment: Well, it's a question not about CodeIgniter, but in general - if you build a website with URL structure of /xxx/yyy/zzz, how do you build links? Something like HOME_DIR . $link;
Same here. Of course, another option would be just to link to home dir / (<a href=/xxx/yyy/zzz>), but in localhost case / would refer to localhost, not to localhost/ci

Answer (score 0):

maybe create virtual host for CI folder!

go -> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\host
add line -> 127.0.0.1       localhost localhost2 localhost3

then go to webserver httpd.conf file and add:

```
<VirtualHost localhost2>
    ServerName localhost2
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/project2"

    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/project2">
        allow from all
        order allow,deny
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost localhost3>
    ServerName localhost3
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/CI"

    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/CI">
        allow from all
        order allow,deny
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart webserver!
And now to view your CI folder type in browser -> loaclhost3